# What is meant by それはそれで面白い in this sentence

Tags: meaning

To provide some additional context, Girl 1 and Boy 1 are thought to be dating by lots of people (they are very close to one another, but they are not officially dating at least). 烈 wanted to make Girl 1 his girlfriend so he challenged Boy 1 to a fight, Boy 1 cheated and won. They were then discussing this later where the following occurs:

> Girl 1 「反論されても……烈さんの男気に比べるとどうしてもなぁ……」
>
> Girl 2 「んん！？ まさか浮気の予感！？」
>
> Girl 1「まだ付き合ってるとは言ってないよ」
>
> Girl 2「**それはそれで面白いけどさ**」
>
> Boy 1 「面白くない！！」

I think I understand the usage of それはそれで, however I am not quite sure what she is saying is 面白い from the previous utterance 「まだ付き合ってるとは言ってないよ」.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Girl 2 said それはそれで面白い ("that's also interesting in its own way") referring to 浮気, not 言ってない. Simply, Girl 2 "ignored" what Girl 1 just said, and stated that if Girl 1 and 烈 should start dating, that's also welcome to her.