# 向こうも向こうで What does this mean in this context ? (mukou mo mukou de) Is this some kind of Japanese Idiom?

Tags: grammar, translation, idioms, japanese-to-english, conversations

Context: MC talking with 2 girls in his team. The detective (who was helping MC to clear his name from the false accusation of police and find out who is the real murderer) has left the crime investigation after received a warning letter from the culprit.

> G1: まったく勝手な奴だわ。
>
> G2:察するに……犯人に脅迫をされているようだな。
>
> MC: 脅迫…
>
> G2: 向こうも向こうで (I don't understand this line) こちらの動きをある程度掴んでいるということだ。油断は出来ないな。

Can someone give me the English translation of the last sentence?

My guess: "G2: The opponent (the culprit) can also do whatever he wants to us. It means that our opponent has already got some idea of our movements. I guess we can't let our guard down now."

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a variant of the `AはAで` construction that has been asked several times on this site:

- [Meaning of あいつはあいつで](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/78118/5010)
- [What is the meaning of あいつはあいつで?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/21167/5010)
- [What is meant by それはそれで面白い in this sentence](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/68881/5010)

This も means "also", but since `AはAで` already means A is similar to what's already mentioned, `AもAで` is usually interchangeable with `AはAで`. 向こうも向こうで and 向こうは向こうで are almost the same.

> 向こうも向こうでこちらの動きをある程度掴んでいるということだ。
> That is, (just as we know what they are doing,) they have some idea of what we are doing, too.

Comment: So this phrase should be translated as "The opponent is also like us / can do it like us too "?

Comment: @4chanuser Yes, but the connotation is "they may be using some different means but the conclusion is the same" or "they have their own way of knowing what we are doing", as explained in the first link.

Answer (score 2):

The repeat is used to highlight the subject:

- 向こう「も」向こうで ...

"On the other side, they are「also」... getting our moves."

- あっち「は」あっちで頑張っている。

"They. They 「are」 putting effort there."