# What does 香代は香代で (Kayo wa Kayo de) mean in this context ?[A husband is speaking about his wife's career, explains why she left him and their child] ]

Tags: grammar, meaning, japanese-to-english

when reading i met this sentence but not sure about this part ,much thanks if anyone can explain to me its meaning

「**香代は香代で**、考古学研究の第一人者ですから。そんな人間を、私と穂花で独り占めするのはもったいない」

My guess : "Because Kayo (his wife who went oversea for a business trip) is a leading expert/No.1 in archaeological research. It would be a waste for me and Honoka( their small daughter) to keep such a person to ourselves."

Please correct me if i was wrong or missing any meaning o/

Comment: Related: [向こうも向こうで What does this mean in this context ? (mukou mo mukou de) Is this some kind of Japanese Idiom?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/85868/41067)

Comment: See also https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/78118.